# new centos os servers, nfs mounting is really slow

Tags: linux-networking, nfs

So i am setting up two new boxes (actually linodes)

nfs.server - CentOS release 6.2
in my /etc/export i have

```
/home/unit  192.168.131.103(sync,insecure,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,rw)
/home/voice 192.168.131.103(sync,insecure,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,rw)
```

on my web.server1 CentOS release 5.6 when I mount either it takes

```
mount 192.168.139.92:/home/voice /voice
```

it takes 25 seconds to mount. The two servers HAVE to stay the centos versions they are.

Any idea on why this takes so long and how i would debug this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: And why do they HAVE to stay on old releases? That's quite risky, you know.

Comment: I have third party binaries that i have to use that only work with CentOS release 5

Comment: But you're on 5.6 so you're missing over two years of security updates!

Comment: Check DNS or put IPs in /etc/hosts of both servers. Do you use NIS or something else to exchange the users between hosts ? Check the logs if there is something written.

Comment: What's the latency between the client and servers?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the help.
I am nuking this box and rebuilding it to match the same version as the nfs box and then loading the 32 bit drivers to try to make it work.
Thanks